# How to properly use this while loop within my method to have user retry input to a maximum of three times

Tags: java, while-loop

Hi I am creating a mock atm, and I created a method to check if the user's pin is inputted wrong, but if it is wrong it spams incorrect pin 3 times then my program stops, I am looking at how to have the user input incorrectly have it tell them it is wrong once then have them retry their pin until they reach the max 3 attempts.

My while loop is with my ATM class (First time posting bare with me)

MAIN

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner enterPin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your 4 digit pin: ");
        String userPin = enterPin.nextLine();
        ATM pin = new ATM("1234");
        pin.checkPin(userPin);
    }
}
```

ATM CLASS

```
public class ATM {
    String pin;
    int counter;
    public ATM(String pin){ //constructor 1 for pin
        this.pin = pin;
    }
    public ATM(int counter){ //constructor for counting how many times pin is entered
        this.counter = counter;
    }
    public String getPin(){
        return pin;
    }
    public boolean setPin(String pin){
        this.pin = pin;
        return true;
    }
    public boolean checkPin(String userPin){
        while(!userPin.contains(pin) && counter < 3) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect pin.");
                counter += 1;
            if (counter >= 3){
                System.out.println("Incorrect pin your account has been blocked.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(userPin.contains(pin)){
            System.out.println("Your pin is correct!");
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not a well structured question. What problem are you facing? besides your original question "How to break this while loop"

Comment: Well of course it spams "Incorrect pin".  The only thing that changes inside the loop body is the value of `counter`, so if it is initially the case that `userPin` does not contain `pin`, then that will be the case on every iteration.  If you want to accept a new pin before the next check then put that inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any user input in your code (i.e no Scanner to take in user input), so what's happening is userPin stays the same throughout each loop.

[userPin is false --> count++ --> print "Incorrect pin"] repeats 3 times, that's why it spams 3 times.

Here's the code I've rewritten:

```
public boolean checkPin() {
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(counter < 3) {
        String userPin = scanner.nextLine();
        if(userPin.contains(pin)){
            System.out.println("Your pin is correct!");
            return true;
        }
        System.out.println("Incorrect pin.");
        counter += 1;
    }
    System.out.println("Too many tries, your account has been blocked.");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: there is sorry it is in my main class, I just only provided my method

Comment: But thank you this was helpful!

Comment: Glad I could help : D If you find it helpful, can you upvote my answer? I need some more points to unlock features here haha

Comment: cant upvote yet my friend sorry but I would if could.